# How to compare predicted vs real frequency data?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, frequency

I have a machine learning approach that counts cars in jpeg images. For each image, I have a predicted count of the number of cars from the machine learning approach and a real count of the number of cars based on a human's count. This is what the dataset looks like:

```
             predicted_cars   real_cars
Image_1      2                1
Image_2      6                7
Image_3      0                0
Image_4      0                1
Image_5      0                0
Image_6      1                1
...
Image_5000   4                3
```

My initial thought would be to use a linear regression, although since this dataset has discrete count data I assume that would be inappropriate. Additionally, since the majority of counts will likely be 0, this is likely to influence the statistics.

What approach can I take to statistically and/or graphically assess how well the predicted car counts compare to the "real" car counts? I am working in Python with scikit-learn and pandas.

Comment: https://analyse-it.com/docs/user-guide/fit-model/linear/predicted-actual-plot

Comment: @yatu Thanks for the answer. I will be investigating MSE. The graphical approach probably will not work in my case because of the tremendous amount of images I am working with.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the accuracy of the result here is quite trivial, you could take the [mean absolute error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) or the [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) for instance. You can find a wide variety of error metrics in [`sklearn.metrics`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics).

And for a visual representation of the results, one way would be to plot a stacked bar chart:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For accuracy, pick a score metric eg:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error